# call controller with plain javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-ajax

how can I use pure javascript rather than jquery or any external library to call a controller in MVC

controller

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeMethod(string key, string value)
    {
      return this.Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $.post('/SomeController /SomeMethod', 
           { key : "TestKey", value : 'Test' }, function (data) 
    {
        alert("Success " + data.success);
    });
});
```

what is the equivalent syntax of above jquery in javascript

Comment: look at [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: You may take also a look at [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost4.shtml) which helped me a lot.

Comment: thanks both of them were useful to me